# Joining many callisto images

Tags: python-2.7

c1 = CallistoSpectrogram.read('BIR_20110922_101500_01.fit')

c2 = CallistoSpectrogram.read('BIR_20110922_103000_01.fit')

d = CallistoSpectrogram.join_many([c1, c2])

If I want to join approximately 40 files like this, it is throwing the following error

ValueError: Too large gap.

Is there any limit in number?

Answer (score 1):

This error is an internal error of the sunpy package that you are using.  Really your question is not to do with python but to do with that package.  You need to tag it with that.

But we can see what's going on by looking at the source, eg [here](http://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/_modules/sunpy/spectra/spectrogram.html#LinearTimeSpectrogram.join_many).  It shows that the ValueError is thrown when two adjacent spectra are separated by more than the `maxgap` parameter which defaults to zero.

So one fix might be simply to pass in `maxgap = None`

```
d = CallistoSpectrogram.join_many([c1, c2],maxgap = None)
```

That assumes you don't mind the gaps, of course.